# setInterval animation

Tags: javascript, setinterval

http://jsfiddle.net/vzBZB/5/

```
(function(){
var i = 1;
var start = true;   
    setInterval(function(){
        if (i>0&&start){
         var o = $("#box").css("opacity");

            var s = parseFloat(o) - 0.1;

            $("#box").css("opacity", s.toString());
           i = s;    
        }

        else {
        start = false;
         var o = $("#box").css("opacity");
        var s = parseFloat(o) + 0.1;

         $("#box").css("opacity", s.toString());
        i = s; 

        if (i==1) start = true;
        }




    }, 100);


})();
```

This code does simple animation - it goes from opacity 1 to 0 and back to 1. But i would like to perform this cycle infinitely. i used  `if (i==1) start = true;` but it doesnt help. how do i fix? Second question: when it stops opacity is 1.1. Why? How do i fix?

Comment: You should try doing it with Jquery's .animate()... it's gonna make your life MUCH simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just set "start" back to true when you're done fading back in.  Such as:

```
start = false;
var o = $("#box").css("opacity");
var s = parseFloat(o) + 0.1;

$("#box").css("opacity", s.toString());
i = s;
if(s >= 1) start = true; //Reset for next loop
```

Here's my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vzBZB/8/

Comment: I'm not sure.  `i == 1` works when I try it.  Did you have the code in the right spot?  Comparing a `float` to an `int` might be somewhat inaccurate depending on browser, OS, CPU type, etc.  Using the greater than operator is a far better idea.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vzBZB/11/ this is how i tried.. why does it go to 1.1?? How do i make it go to 1.0??

Comment: Just change `if(s > 1) start = true;` to `if(s >= 1) start = true;`

Comment: Not for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome 15.0. What's yours??

Comment: My guess is that the last iteration of `i`, it gets set to like `.999999999997` or something.  Floating point numbers are somewhat not exact.  Thus, it triggers one more loop on your browser or JS runtime or whatever.  Maybe you can make it `if(s >= .95)` to be safe?

Comment: Yea like on Firefox, instead of 0.8 I get `0.7999999999999999` - but the other numbers work fine.  Maybe the Chrome runtime handles floating points differently.  Are you just doing this to learn?  There's plenty of Javascript animation libraries that rock.

Comment: That's cool.  Always good to learn.  BTW, I tried it on Chrome on my Mac, and the last number is like .99999999997 or something.  So yea floating point math is kinda weird.  Anyway if my answer helped you, I'd appreciate the "Accept"..

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to simply use the callback parameter of .fadeToggle recursively. See my update to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzBZB/6/.

Answer (score 0):

You arent setting start back to true when it gets back to full opacity...

add this

```
if (o >= 1){
    start=true;   
}
```

full code:

```
(function(){
var i = 1;
var start = true;   
    setInterval(function(){
        if (i>0&&start){
         var o = $("#box").css("opacity");

            var s = parseFloat(o) - 0.1;

            $("#box").css("opacity", s.toString());
           i = s;    
        }

        else {
        start = false;
         var o = $("#box").css("opacity");
        var s = parseFloat(o) + 0.1;

         $("#box").css("opacity", s.toString());
        i = s; 

        if (o >= 1){
            start=true;   
        }

        }




    }, 100);


})();
```